# Mage/Core/Model/Translate.php creates warning in log

Tags: magento-1.9, log

my log is filled up with this warnings:

```
2016-04-18T07:13:09+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: array_key_exists(): The first argument should be either a string or an integer  in /html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Translate.php on line 569
2016-04-18T07:15:28+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: array_key_exists(): The first argument should be either a string or an integer  in /html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Translate.php on line 569
2016-04-18T07:15:28+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: array_key_exists(): The first argument should be either a string or an integer  in /html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Translate.php on line 569
2016-04-18T07:15:28+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: array_key_exists(): The first argument should be either a string or an integer  in /html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Translate.php on line 569
2016-04-18T07:15:28+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: array_key_exists(): The first argument should be either a string or an integer  in /html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Translate.php on line 569
2016-04-18T07:15:42+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: array_key_exists(): The first argument should be either a string or an integer  in /html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Translate.php on line 569
2016-04-18T07:15:42+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: array_key_exists(): The first argument should be either a string or an integer  in /html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Translate.php on line 569
2016-04-18T07:15:42+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: array_key_exists(): The first argument should be either a string or an integer  in /html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Translate.php on line 569
2016-04-18T07:15:42+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: array_key_exists(): The first argument should be either a string or an integer  in /html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Translate.php on line 569
2016-04-18T07:15:42+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: array_key_exists(): The first argument should be either a string or an integer  in /html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Translate.php on line 569
2016-04-18T07:15:58+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: array_key_exists(): The first argument should be either a string or an integer  in /html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Translate.php on line 569
2016-04-18T07:15:58+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: array_key_exists(): The first argument should be either a string or an integer  in /html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Translate.php on line 569
```

How can I find the file which calls this function, to solve this warning?

Comment: you are probably calling somewhere in the code `$this->__($a)` where `$a` is not a string (array maybe, or object).

Comment: what @Marius said. For example, if it's an XML node, you have to explicitly convert it to string: `__((string) $node)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 569 of core/Mage/Core/Model/Translate.php is:

```
elseif (array_key_exists($text, $this->getData()))
```

Which is part of the function

```
protected function _getTranslatedString($text, $code)
```

If you use something like phpstorm you should be be to find usages of that function. I'd assume it's a module you have installed in community or local. Something could be overwriting the Mage_Core_Model_Translate

Answer (score 1):

Try *temporarily* putting this in the first line of the `_getTranslatedString` method in `core/Mage/Core/Model/Translate.php`

```
    try {
        if ((!is_string($text) && !is_int($text)) || (!is_string($code) && !is_int($code))) {
            Mage::log(var_export(debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS), true), null, 'translateError.log', true);
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Mage::logException($e);
    }
```

Once you see the warning appear in the logs again, go look at `translateError.log` for a stack trace of what code called `__()` and correct the issue. Repeat until you don't get any warnings anymore.

(For me, something was calling `if ($this->__('Filter' == 'Category'))` instead of `if ($this->__('Filter') == 'Category')` which resolved to a boolean.)